# No scanner in Gimp 2.10 Bionic

Tags: networking, scanner, gimp, xsane

In 18.04, have a networked Brother MFC-J870DW, which works fine in gscan2pdf, Simple Scan & Gimp 2.8.  However, Gimp 2.10 can't find it. Meaning, there is no scanner listed when I select File > Create. I suspect I need to point Gimp to xsane. Looking for help to do this. Thanks.

Comment: How did you installed GIMP (from PPA or as a Snap)?

Comment: I installed using Ubuntu Software (Flatpak).

Comment: Try to install from PPA or from Canonical deb-repository. Maybe Flatpak version does not have scanner interface ...

Comment: Tried uninstalling GIMP before doing  a fresh install, which posted this:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.22-z) but 2.10.4+om-0ubu18.04.1~ppa is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.8.22-z) but 2.10.4+om-0ubu18.04.1~ppa is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I was able to remove the unmet dependencies in Synaptic and reinstall GIMP 2.10.4.  However, my network scanner is still not acquired.  Scan2pdf, Simple Scan & Skanlite all work perfectly.

Comment: [Solved] - Removed the Ubuntu Flatpak version and reinstalled using the PPA.  The GIMP File > Create menu now shows XSane & xscanimage.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Added your/our solution as answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a ppa, just

`sudo apt install xsane`

Comment: This solved the problem for me

Comment: I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10, GIMP 2.10.14 (PPA version) and XSANE 0.999-7 and I don't have the direct SCAN option into the FILE menu. How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks! Worked also for me on Debian Bullseye 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux with GIMP 2.10.22 and XSane 0.999.

Answer (score 1):

As you have installed GIMP as FlatPak I suggest to remove this FlatPak version with

```
flatpak uninstall flathub org.gimp.GIMP
```

and then install normal deb-based version 2.8 with

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

or get 2.10 from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Just saying, for 19.10 it's already 2.10 with default repositories